# Bash: Literal string for special characters in printf

Tags: bash

How do you print out the literal string of special character in bash? I always get the expand `\t` character. For example the code below:

```
value="0.1"
ln=5
thestring=$(printf $'%si \
    var1=$(dpkg-query -s "$1" |  grep \'Package:\' | sed \'s/^.*: //\') \
    var2=$(grep -m 1 "^$1$(printf \'%s\').*$(printf \'%s\')$value" file.txt) \
' "$ln" "\\t" "\\t")
sed "$thestring" -i somefile.txt
```

For `var2` the `\t` character is expanded, I expected an output that looks like:

```
var2=$(grep -m 1 "^$1$(printf '\t').*$(printf '\t')$value" file.txt)
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: What subsequent command(s) are you running with `$thestring` to get your var2 output?

Comment: Edited the question, that string will be appended into a file (bash script) using `sed`, that's why single quotes were used to dynamically modify some value such as `ln`.

Comment: Can you precise your intention? If you plan on batch updating scripts/files, maybe sed is not the right tool. Maybe you could look at using the diff patch format instead.

Comment: Tangentially related but you can use `dpkg-query -Wf '${Package}\n' "$1"` instead of `dpkg-query -s "$1" |  grep \'Package:\' | sed \'s/^.*: //\'`